# Compatibility issue of Internet Explorer with html2canvas or with the HTML/CSS code or the JavaScript used

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to capture an image with text typed on it. The text is typed by the user and the size of the text and textbox is dependent on the number of words with constraints on the maximum size possible (which is based on size of the image at the background). This is done through a JavaScript function. All of this works without any problem on Chrome and Firefox.

However, on Internet Explorer 11, the image at the background is captured properly, but the text becomes smaller in size. This may be a compatibility issue of Internet Explorer with html2canvas or with the HTML/CSS code or the JavaScript used. Would appreciate any guidance to fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091863/html2canvas-code-not-working-ie-11 Support is poor in IE11.

Comment: The only way to "fix" it is using own code.

Comment: did you assign width and height in capturing area??

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal The capturing area div takes the height and width of the image. The height and width of the text which is typed by the user on the image is a percentage of the height and width of the image. I define the percentage in a JavaScript function. This is required to keep the design responsive.