# HTML2Canvas not capturing canvas with a SVG rendered in it in IE 11

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using HTML2Canvas in my application to capture different pages, and one of the pages that I need to capture contains a grid that looks like this:

[image]

The picture above has a structure like this one in HTML:

```
<div>
   <canvas class="pic-canvas" width="100" height="150" style="....">
</div>

<div>
   <canvas class="grid-canvas" width="100" height="150" style="....">
</div>
```

While the grid itself is rendered well and converted correctly to be used later in the pdf, the canvas with the picture which is behind the one with the grid is not rendered at all. I already tried to export only the canvas with the pic, while ignoring everything else and nothing is rendered, but the space where the canvas should be is taken in the resulted canvas, only that is empty.

Here is a pic of the result after HTML2Canvas does its job:

[image]

This happens only in IE 11, in Chrome, Edge and Firefox everything is working well and the grid is exported exactly as it is seen in the first image.

The options I use for HTML2Canvas are the following ones:

```
html2canvas(clone, {
            useCORS: true,
            logging: false,
            scale: window.devicePixelRatio && window.devicePixelRatio >= 1 ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1,
          })
```

I am using HTML2Canvas RC5, the latest version available on NPM.

Not using IE 11 is not an option, since my client requires full IE 11 support alongside newer browsers. The application uses Angular 9 with target es5.

Did anyone else encounter this problem before?

Comment: Why are you trying to support IE11, the rest of the internet doesn't anymore. Show a notification for the users to switch to edge browser when you detect IE11.

Comment: Not possible, the requirement from my client is to support IE 11 and I have no choice regarding that.

Comment: You have my sympathies. Please edit in the reason for your  ie11 requirement into your question at the top. Then I'll remove my comments

Comment: Does the second answer on this question solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091863/html2canvas-code-not-working-ie-11

Comment: Sadly it didn't fix the issue. I forgot to mention I use html2canvas on other pages also, some pretty complex, and everything works ok. I already have multiple polyfills provided, so I don't receive any Promise not defined error.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example in a snippet?

Comment: @Tschallacka I am working on a mockup now but stack blitz doesn't work on IE 11 so I don't know how it can be tested there.

Comment: Make one on github or post the mockup code. Most coders knowhow to transfer that to a local html file :-)

Comment: @Tschallacka fair enough, I thought it would be easier to just not download anything. Anyway I edited my post with an example that uses the same logic that I use on project and reproduces the bug. (with unnecessary code removed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219318/discussion-between-tschallacka-and-artyomska).